# Ensure that clean-up code is executed even after '@Timeout'

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

As titled

For example, I have below test cases.

```
class StartupTest {


    def deploymentPath = "build/milestone/deployment"

    void checkConnectedProducts(){
        def productConnected = XXXhelper.countConnectedProducts()
        //Called another function in another class to check the number of connected products, every 1 sec
        while (productConnected>2){
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            productConnected = XXXhelper.countConnectedProducts()
        }
    }

    int countError(){
        def error = xxx.logFinder.search("(ERROR)",TimeFrames.from(LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(20)).to(LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(20)))
        return error.size()
    }

    @Timeout(80)
    def 'Start_test'() {

    setup:
    //do some setup here

    when: 'Test_started'
    //do something here

    and: 'Check_something'
    //check something here

    then: 'Validate_something'
    checkConnectedProducts()

    cleanup:
    //Call the function in another class to zip the file and send out message to slack
    File log = new File("$deploymentPath/logs")
    def error = countError()
    def zipFile = "xxx.zip"
    IOHelper.createZip(log,zipFile)
    File zipFile = new File(zipFile)

    //Pass the zip to another class
    ZipUploader.Slack(zipFile,error)   

   }
}
```

Below class is used to upload zipped file and send message to slack channel

```
class ZipUploader {

    static uploadLocation = System.getProperty("benchmark-result-server")
    static proxyHost = System.getProperty("proxy-host")
    static proxyPort = System.getProperty("proxy-port")

    static Slack(File file, int errorCount){

        //Upload file
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient()
        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("zip", file.name,
                        RequestBody.create(file, MediaType.parse(com.google.common.net.MediaType.ZIP.type()))
                )
                .build()

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("$uploadLocation/!/xxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build()

        //Check the response
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new Exception("File cannot be uploaded" + response)

        //Slack
        OkHttpClient clientSlack = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)))
                .build()
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n    \"text\": \"Test has been finished \\t Error Log: $errorCount"\n}")
        Request requestSlack = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx?Content-type=application/json")
                .method("POST", body)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build()
        Response responseSlack = clientSlack.newCall(requestSlack).execute()

        //Check the response
        if (!responseSlack.isSuccessful()) throw new Exception("Failed to send message to slack " + responseSlack)

    }
}
```

So if the test run within 80sec, the function in cleanup can be execute successfully, but I also want the function to execute even the test exceed timeout, I don't know how to achieve it.

It will just stopped the whole test in the middle if the test exceed timeout and return timeout exception, and the function under cleanup: will not be executed, including the function to upload zip and send slack notice.

Comment: In my tests locally, it works as expected...  even if the cleanup method takes time, it will keep trying until it has finished (and output `[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'test timeout' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 4.00 seconds.` each time it tries...  Do you have a simple example that shows the error you say is happening?

Comment: ```
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 0.50 seconds.

Method timed out after 80.00 seconds
Method timed out after 80.00 seconds
 at xxxxxxxxxx.StartupTest.checkConnected(StartupTest.groovy:36)(StartupTest.groovy:36)
 at xxxxxxxxxx.Start_Test(StartupTest.groovy:71)
1 test completed, 1 failed
```

And the test just ended, all the line didn't proceed after timeout. The test stopped at "then:" block.

Comment: How long does `ZipUploader.Slack()` take?

Comment: It depends, in real test it may need a while to zip the large log, and the timeout will be larger. For now, I just generate small log to test and it just a few sec to zip and so I just set a small timeout. Maybe it is related to the other function in the "and: "block? You can take a look from above update. I have called 2 functions to check connected products and count the error in log. I tried to removed those two function, the log folder will be still zip after timeout, but if those two functions are in the block, it will just stopped there if timeout, and not proceed to zip the log file.

Comment: in the "then:" block, not "and:" block

Answer (score 0):

#### Revised answer (2022-02-27)

I want to revise my previous statements with regard to

- how I was emulating the situation and
- how I was interpreting the results:

Because I had a similar use case and used my example from here as a starting point, I noticed that there is a fundamental difference between

- JRE's `Thread.sleep(long)`,
- Groovy's `sleep(long)` and
- Groovy's `sleep(long, Closure)`.

See also [this article](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2016/10/groovy-goodness-interrupted-sleeping.html).

I was using both `Thread.sleep` (in `checkConnectedProducts()`) and simple `sleep` (in the `cleanup:` block and the method called from there), which is why the result was the way it is shown in the log output.

**Please note that `Thread.sleep` is interruptible, while `sleep` is not!** Only an extended Groovy variant like `sleep(4000), { e -> true }` is also interruptable.

I.e., when the timeout occurs and Spock tries to interrupt the test, it successfully interrupts the `Thread.sleep` in `checkConnectedProducts`, but then immediately the two non-interruptible `sleep 4000` variants are called from the `cleanup:` block, which means that they ignore Spock's repeated tries to interrupt them too, as you can see in the console log. If there we would also use an interruptible sleep or simply normal, interruptible Groovy or Java code, the `cleanup:` block or methods called from there would indeed also be interrupted by Spock quickly.

Now, assuming that you really need to make sure that the clean-up code is executed, even if the method gets interrupted by `@Timeout`, you simply move the clean-up code from the `cleanup:` block to a `cleanup()` method (which then gets executed for each feature method in the Spock specification). Look at this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60601740

import spock.lang.Issue
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Timeout

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis

@Issue("https://stackoverflow.com/a/60610944/1082681")
class StartupTest extends Specification {
  static final int SLEEP_MILLIS = 5000
  static final int TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 3000

  def startTime = currentTimeMillis()

  def timeElapsed() {
    currentTimeMillis() - startTime
  }

  void checkConnectedProducts() {
    printf "%6d | checkConnectedProducts, sleeping %d ms%n", timeElapsed(), SLEEP_MILLIS
    // Interruptable
    Thread.sleep SLEEP_MILLIS
    // Non-interruptable
    // sleep SLEEP_MILLIS
    // Interruptable
    // sleep SLEEP_MILLIS, { true }
    printf "%6d | checkConnectedProducts finished%n", timeElapsed()
  }

  int countError() {
    printf "%6d | countError, sleeping %d ms%n", timeElapsed(), SLEEP_MILLIS
    // Interruptable, but will not be interrupted by '@Timeout' when called from method 'cleanup'
    Thread.sleep SLEEP_MILLIS
    printf "%6d | countError finished%n", timeElapsed(), SLEEP_MILLIS
    return 3
  }

  @Timeout(value = TIMEOUT_MILLIS, unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  def 'Start_test'() {
    expect: 'Validate_something'
    checkConnectedProducts()
  }

  /**
   * Even if a feature method (including its 'cleanup:' block) times out and gets aborted,
   * the 'cleanup' method will be executed.
   */
  def cleanup() {
    countError()
    printf "%6d | cleanup, sleeping %d ms%n", timeElapsed(), SLEEP_MILLIS
    // Interruptable, but will not be interrupted by '@Timeout' within method 'cleanup'
    Thread.sleep SLEEP_MILLIS
    printf "%6d | cleanup finished%n", timeElapsed()
    // Verify that really as much time has elapsed as we expect, i.e. 'cleanup()' has not been interrupted
    assert timeElapsed() >= TIMEOUT_MILLIS + SLEEP_MILLIS + SLEEP_MILLIS
  }
}
```

The console log says:

```
   143 | checkConnectedProducts, sleeping 5000 ms
  3138 | countError, sleeping 5000 ms
  8147 | countError finished
  8151 | cleanup, sleeping 5000 ms
 13157 | cleanup finished

Method timed out after 3,00 seconds

    at app//org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
    at app//de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60601740.StartupTest.checkConnectedProducts(StartupTest.groovy:25)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60601740.StartupTest.Start_test(StartupTest.groovy:44)
```

[Try in in the Groovy web console.](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJy9VU1P20AQvedXjJCQEwh2KDSlSK2QaA6R-JISuEab3THest519yOAKP-9YztOCCSIA-rRs2_G772Z2S0Yv2O3CAJjx23IJzlzHm3sPB2YGdpUmfv4T7_X7-1_O-y1WjIvjPXgCsPvYsX0bTx0LuCa-KhALlPJmZdGrzkfyxxN8IuSv9mMxcFLFXOjebAWta9A11ouUUTMS16D6988EuE8nieU-HOplHSt1knFrL2VeV-44yRZ1cRNnrCEhO33vh8eJvu9oy_9o_2tTosr5hyMPLM-FGN0HvDBoxYUe6kInlrQsEmlZgqk9jA6GwyuJufDs7PhCH7A116vtw42Hp4PLq_HS-BBCSSkwLRE20oIxd_IancamKfYQLHCoWh3KjawDg57y4KEeS7TZ0YK4Bnyu1OjNXKP4soaEbh3i1KFJaIpbG33BfzdAO6CU4iF1LewLSB323qru8qru-JIVThJYKhpxmwoPJsqrILjzCITcVVubcqF0XvyTRodbE55-5e18C48gbcByZqP6i47KV2G4q3gxuKyy9wE7QfWGrvJ1QXgU5zswjR4uKfGgzYepggLx1DA9BGik_nSRXCfoQbOlKKT1JoccvSZERBxhUyHIvpAWzaJeceeNSos-mA1HDTONRzbM6ZCuQOry9KFQPdBGZ5fDXEdH5xeXvwadebLEVX7O_G0vtHCfHygBfbHEN0wJQXzOHGmlE2u13I3rURDLdnZKXE7MJiRezIFBikyoo-NfW2puQqi7KOkOWncPI5gqujm61RuOCB5wLSAWyQQm9LFhqJbl_YZLpvQlK16Sv3EB-SBsHGFTeZi5-jlLfBi7tY1qob__5GTpdWfMGh14vtLWFG9QSvTR7KUeRozGvZHYA7ywLMKDxl9YZ1UHtzjfES6IGOMFxTbnaiC1grLzi81Vr-iBwPpbVq9kX--nlzYXX0edl8LfW49t_4Bnc9v9Q)

See? The test method gets interrupted after 3 seconds, but the 5 + 5 = 10 extra seconds in `cleanup()` fully elapse, i.e. after cleanup we have a total of 13 elapsed seconds in the log.

If you want to speed up the test, simply change the static constants from 5000/3000 to 500/300.

BTW, you can also add a separate `@Timeout` to `cleanup()` or any other fixture method, but that is a bit out of scope here.

#### Original answer

I cannot reproduce your problem, given the code snippets you have provided instead of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I replicated a simplified version of your situation like this, just replacing the operations consuming time in your example by Groovy `sleep` or Java `Thread.sleep` statements:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60601740

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Timeout

import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis

class StartupTest extends Specification {
  def startTime = currentTimeMillis()

  def timeElapsed() {
    currentTimeMillis() - startTime
  }

  void checkConnectedProducts() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      println "${timeElapsed()} | checkConnectedProducts #$i, sleeping 1 s"
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }

  int countError() {
    println "${timeElapsed()} | countError, sleeping 4 s"
    sleep 4000
    return 3
  }

  @Timeout(3)
  def 'Start_test'() {
    setup:
    true

    when: 'Test_started'
    true

    and: 'Check_something'
    true

    then: 'Validate_something'
    checkConnectedProducts()

    cleanup:
    countError()
    println "${timeElapsed()} | cleanup, sleeping 4 s"
    sleep 4000
    println "${timeElapsed()} | cleanup finished"
  }
}
```

The console log looks as expected:

```
64 | checkConnectedProducts #1, sleeping 1 s
1112 | checkConnectedProducts #2, sleeping 1 s
2114 | checkConnectedProducts #3, sleeping 1 s
3011 | countError, sleeping 4 s
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 0,50 seconds.
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 1,00 seconds.
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 2,00 seconds.
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 4,00 seconds.
7012 | cleanup, sleeping 4 s
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 8,00 seconds.
11012 | cleanup finished

Method timed out after 3,00 seconds

    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60601740.StartupTest.checkConnectedProducts(StartupTest.groovy:18)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60601740.StartupTest.Start_test(StartupTest.groovy:40)
```

As you can see, the first 3 iterations of the `for` loop, each expending ~1 s, are being executed before the 3 s timeout interrupts the test in the method called from the `then:` block. After that, the cleanup block runs completely, both the called method and the direct `sleep`, each spending ~4 s in addition to the 3 elapsed seconds. All in all we have 3 + 4 + 4 = 11 seconds, so everything works as expected.

Unless you can provide an MCVE reproducing your problem as Tim asked you to already, I would think there is no problem in Spock but rather something you misinterpret from your log output or another problem in your code which you did not show to us, such as a cleanup or zip operation done in an extra thread.

Comment: Please note that I have massively updated my answer with more information, not only explaining why your `cleanup:` block was interrupted and why in my example it was not, but also showing how you can avoid the interruption by simplymoving the clean-up code into a `cleanup()` method.

Comment: I hope that now you can accept and upvote my answer, because I guess now there are no more mysteries or open questions. Sorry to only find the correct explanation and solution after almost two years, but I had a recent reason to re-investigate this and wanted to let you know about it.

Answer (score 0):

@kriegaex, thanks you for your answer. For my error log, it returns as below.

```
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 0.50 seconds.
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 1.00 seconds.
[spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 2.00 seconds.

Method timed out after 70.00 seconds
Method timed out after 70.00 seconds
    at app//xxx.checkConnectedProducts(StartupTest.groovy:36)
    at xxx.StartupTest.Start_test(StartupTest.groovy:71)

xxx.StartupTest > Start_test STANDARD_OUT
    [spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 0.50 seconds.
    [spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 1.00 seconds.
    [spock.lang.Timeout] Method 'Start_test' has not yet returned - interrupting. Next try in 2.00 seconds.
Gradle Test Executor 4 finished executing tests.
> Task :test
TRACE [startup log cleaner] StartupLogFactory - Flushing delayed logs as application terminates...
TRACE [startup log cleaner] StartupLogFactory - Caution: timestamps are those at the time of the flush!
DEBUG [startup log cleaner] Connector - Connecting to localhost:6450 with user admin
TRACE [startup log cleaner] StartupLogFactory - Finished flushing delayed logs.
xxx.StartupTest > Start_test FAILED
    Method timed out after 70.00 seconds
        at app//xxx.StartupTest.checkConnectedProducts(StartupTest.groovy:36)
        at xxx.StartupTest.Start_test(StartupTest.groovy:71)
DEBUG [pool-10-thread-2] Connector - Connecting to 0.0.0.0:6450 with user <null>
1 test completed, 1 failed
```

It just stopped at the checkConnectedProducts(). And do not proceed `IOHelper.createZip(log,zipFile)` under cleanup: block.

I tried to add println("abc") under cleanup: block, indeed it can be executed after timeout, but not the zip function and upload zip class function.

Could you advice on how to make `IOHelper.createZip` and also `Zipuploader` under cleanup: block to run after timeout? In my case, they did not proceed. Thanks a lot!!!